# Catchable fatal error on custom category post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, errors

I get this error after deleted a few of unused category's product on my woo theme:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted
>   to string in
>   D:-mytheme\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\myplugin\mymodule.php on line
>   47

The line 47 is like this:

```
 <?php echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term).'">'.$term->name.'</a>'; ?>
```

The $term define on:

```
 <?php 
 class myShortCode {
    protected function content($atts, $content = null){
    $atts =  vc_map_get_attributes( $this->getShortcode(), $atts );
     global $woocommerce, $product; 
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'title' => ''       
    ), $atts ) );
    $term = get_term_by('name', $type_product, 'brands');
    $category = isset($term->term_id) ? $term->term_id : '';    
    $css_class  = "";

    if ( $css_animation != '' ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'waypoints' );
        $css_class = ' wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_'.$css_animation;
}       
 ;
 ob_start();
 ?>
```

The error disappear only id the category exist and selected.

I have no idea how to fix this. Can anyone throw me a bone?

Thank you.

Comment: Before accessing `$term->name` check if it is not wp error object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in the same check used for `$category`:

```
<?php if (isset($term->term_id)) {
    echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term).'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
} ?>
```

or check to make sure it is not an error object:

```
<?php if (!is_wp_error($term)) {
    echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term).'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
} ?>
```